# C++ Builder ignores std::fixed for big numbers

Tags: c++, gcc, c++builder

Consider the following program, which is intended to print a floating point number to three decimal places:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

int main() {
    double val = 1.234567890e50;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);
    ss << val;

    std::cout << ss.str() << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

This number cannot be represented exactly as a double, but that is irrelevant now.

On GCC 5.1, the program prints

> 123456789000000004671007453916432257001527036608512.000

On Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.1 (compiler bcc32c version 3.3.1), the output is:

> 1.234567890000000047000000000000000000000e+50

Why does the C++ Builder output not match the selected floating point notation, which is `std::fixed`? Even if the number is 10^300, GCC shows it using the selected notation.

Why do these two compilers work differently? Does the C++ standard define how the string conversion should work in this case?

Comment: Upvoted. This question has depths that I didn't appreciate at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.1 has a bug.

`std::setprecision(3);` sets the number of digits to display *after* the decimal separator to *exactly* 3, irrespective of whether or not the floating point scheme on that platform can represent that number.

GCC5.1 is compliant with this.

Embarcadero C++ Builder 10.1 is not.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision, which pretty much proxies the C++ standard.

Comment: Had the wrong end of the stick initially; apologies.